# Error in creating Logger wrapper class in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j, wrapper, log4j2

I am trying to upgrade the log4j version in my application and having trouble in rewriting a wrapper class. The application has a Logger wrapper class and uses it to log the statements.

The wrapper class uses a statement

```
static public Category cat = Category.getInstance (Logger.class.getName());
```

and when i try to re write it using `Logger cat = LogManager.getLogger(Logger.class.getName())` i get type cast error -

> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger to Logger" and when i use the type cast i get the error "org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger cannot be cast to Logger"

```
/*
 * $Id: Logger.java,v 1.10 2006/11/09 16:43:24 bh1465 Exp $
 * Created on Aug 4, 2004
 */
package com.sbc.swat.logging ;

import org.apache.log4j.* ;

/**
 * Wrapper for log4j logging utility.
 *
 * @author Brian Holliday
 * @version %I%, %G%
 * @since 1.4
 */
public class Logger
{
    //*******************************************************************/
    //*                                                                 */
    //*         CLASS DATA                                              */
    //*                                                                 */
    //*******************************************************************/

    //*--private class data---------------------------------------------*/

    //*--protected class data-------------------------------------------*/

    //*--package class data---------------------------------------------*/

    //*--public class data----------------------------------------------*/

    //*=================================================================*/
    //* constants for logging                                           */
    //*=================================================================*/
    static public final int ALL     = 0 ;
    static public final int DEBUG   = 0 ;
    static public final int INFO    = 1 ;
    static public final int WARN    = 2 ;
    static public final int ERROR   = 3 ;
    static public final int FATAL   = 4 ;
    static public final int OFF     = 5 ;

    //*=================================================================*/
    //* constants for logging exceptions                                */
    //*=================================================================*/
    static public final int DETAIL_LOW  = 0;
    static public final int DETAIL_MED  = 1;
    static public final int DETAIL_FULL = 2;

    //*=================================================================*/
    static public Category cat = Category.getInstance (Logger.class.getName());

    //*******************************************************************/
    //*                                                                 */
    //*         OBJECT DATA                                             */
    //*                                                                 */
    //*******************************************************************/

    //*--private object data--------------------------------------------*/

    //*--protected object data------------------------------------------*/

    //*--package object data--------------------------------------------*/

    //*--public object data---------------------------------------------*/

    //*******************************************************************/
    //*                                                                 */
    //*         CLASS METHODS                                           */
    //*                                                                 */
    //*******************************************************************/

    //*--private class methods------------------------------------------*/

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* logDetails -- log exception details                             */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log exception details.
     * 
     * @param pad left-side padding before every output line
     * @param e exception
     * @param level ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, or OFF
     */
    static private void logDetails (String pad, Throwable e, int level)
    {
        if (e.getMessage() == null)
        {
            log(level, pad + "Msg: (null)");
        }
        else if (e.getMessage().indexOf('\n') == -1)
        {
            log (level, pad + "Msg  : {" + e.getMessage()  + "}"); 
        }
        else
        {
            String[] lines = e.getMessage().split("\r?\n", -1);

            log(level, pad + "Msg :");
            log(level, pad + "{");
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
            {
                log(level, pad + "   " + lines[i]); 
            }
            log(level, pad + "}");
        }

        log(level, pad + "Excpt: {" + e.getClass()  + "}");
    }

    //*--protected class methods----------------------------------------*/

    //*--package class methods------------------------------------------*/

    //*--public class methods-------------------------------------------*/

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* debug -- log message if at DEBUG level or better                */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log message if at DEBUG level or better.
     * 
     * @param msg output message
     */
    static public void debug (String msg)
    {
        log (DEBUG, msg) ;
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* debug -- log exception if at DEBUG level or better              */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log exception if at DEBUG level or better.
     * 
     * @param e exception
     * @param detail DETAIL_LOW, DETAIL_MED, or DETAIL_FULL
     */
    static public void debug (Throwable e, int detail)
    {
        log (e, DEBUG, detail) ;
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* error -- log message if at ERROR level or better                */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log message if at ERROR level or better.
     * 
     * @param msg output message
     */
    static public void error (String msg)
    {
        log (ERROR, msg) ;
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* error -- log exception if at ERROR level or better              */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log exception if at ERROR level or better.
     * 
     * @param e exception
     * @param detail DETAIL_LOW, DETAIL_MED, or DETAIL_FULL
     */
    static public void error (Throwable e, int detail)
    {
        log (e, ERROR, detail) ;
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* fatal -- log message if at FATAL level or better                */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log message if at FATAL level or better.
     * 
     * @param msg output message
     */
    static public void fatal (String msg)
    {
        log (FATAL, msg) ;
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* fatal -- log exception if at FATAL level or better              */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log exception if at FATAL level or better.
     * 
     * @param e exception
     * @param detail DETAIL_LOW, DETAIL_MED, or DETAIL_FULL
     */
    static public void fatal (Throwable e, int detail)
    {
        log (e, FATAL, detail) ;
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* info -- log message if at INFO level or better                  */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log message if at INFO level or better.
     * 
     * @param msg output message
     */
    static public void info (String msg)
    {
        log (INFO, msg) ;
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* info -- log exception if at INFO level or better                */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log exception if at INFO level or better.
     * 
     * @param e exception
     * @param detail DETAIL_LOW, DETAIL_MED, or DETAIL_FULL
     */
    static public void info (Throwable e, int detail)
    {
        log (e, INFO, detail) ;
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* log -- log message if at appropriate level                      */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log message if at appropriate level.
     * 
     * @param level ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, or OFF
     * @param msg output message
     */
    static public void log (int level, String msg)
    {
        switch (level)
        {
            case DEBUG :
                cat.debug (msg) ;
                break ;
            case INFO :
                cat.info (msg) ;
                break ;
            case WARN :
                cat.warn (msg) ;
                break ;
            case ERROR :
                cat.error (msg) ;
                break ;
            case FATAL :
                cat.fatal (msg) ;
                break ;
            case OFF :
                break ;
            default :
                cat.warn ("Problem using Logger class") ;
        }
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* log -- log exception if at appropriate level                    */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log exception if at appropriate level.
     * 
     * @param e exception
     * @param level ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, or OFF
     * @param detail DETAIL_LOW, DETAIL_MED, or DETAIL_FULL
     */
    static public void log (Throwable e, int level, int detail)
    {
        log ("", e, level, detail) ;
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* log -- log exception if at appropriate level                    */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log exception if at appropriate level.
     * 
     * @param pad left-side padding before every output line
     * @param e exception
     * @param level ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, or OFF
     * @param detail DETAIL_LOW, DETAIL_MED, or DETAIL_FULL
     */
    static public void log (String pad, Throwable e, int level, int detail)
    {
        logDetails (pad, e, level) ;

        logStack (pad, e, level, detail) ;

        if (e.getCause() != null)
        {
            log (level, "");
            log (level, pad + "Nested Error:") ;

            log (pad + "   ", e.getCause(), level, detail) ;
        }
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* logIfData -- log if Boolean datum not null                      */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log if Boolean datum not null.
     * 
     * @param msg output message (before Boolean datum)
     * @param datum Boolean datum
     */
    static public void logIfData (int level, String msg, Boolean datum)
    {
        if (datum != null)
        {
            log (level, msg + " [" + datum.booleanValue() + "]") ;
        }
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* logIfData -- log if Float datum not null                        */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log if Float datum not null.
     * 
     * @param msg output message (before Float datum)
     * @param datum Float datum
     */
    static public void logIfData (int level, String msg, Float datum)
    {
        if (datum != null)
        {
            log (level, msg + " [" + datum + "]") ;
        }
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* logIfData -- log if Long datum not null                         */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log if Long datum not null.
     * 
     * @param msg output message (before Long datum)
     * @param datum Long datum
     */
    static public void logIfData (int level, String msg, Long datum)
    {
        if (datum != null)
        {
            log (level, msg + " [" + datum + "]") ;
        }
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* logIfData -- log if String datum not empty                      */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log if String datum not empty.
     * 
     * @param msg output message (before String datum)
     * @param datum output String datum
     */
    static public void logIfData (int level, String msg, String datum)
    {
        if (datum != null)
        {
            if (datum.equals ("") == false)
            {
                log (level, msg + " [" + datum + "]") ;
            }
        }
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* logIfData -- log if String datum not empty                      */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log if String datum not empty.
     * 
     * @param msg output message (before string datum)
     * @param datum output string datum
     */
    static public void logIfData (String msg, String datum)
    {
        if (datum != null)
        {
            if (datum.equals ("") == false)
            {
                log (INFO, msg + " [" + datum + "]") ;
            }
        }
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* logIfData -- log if int datum not zero                          */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log if int datum not zero.
     * 
     * @param msg output message (before integer datum)
     * @param datum output integer datum
     */
    static public void logIfData (int level, String msg, int datum)
    {
        if (datum != 0)
        {
            log (level, msg + " [" + datum + "]") ;
        }
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* logIfData -- log if integer datum not zero                      */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log if integer datum not zero.
     * 
     * @param msg output message (before integer datum)
     * @param datum output integer datum
     */
    static public void logIfData (String msg, int datum)
    {
        if (datum != 0)
        {
            log (INFO, msg + " [" + datum + "]") ;
        }
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* logStack -- log exception stack                                 */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log exception stack.
     * 
     * @param pad left-side padding before every output line
     * @param e exception
     * @param level ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, or OFF
     * @param detail DETAIL_LOW, DETAIL_MED, or DETAIL_FULL
     */
    static public void logStack(String pad, Throwable e, int level, int detail)
    {
        if (detail <= DETAIL_LOW)
            return;

        StackTraceElement[] trace = e.getStackTrace();
        int till = trace.length;

        if (detail <= DETAIL_MED)
        {
            //This code hides any common stack frames, we should be
            //  left with just the frames between where the exception
            //  was thrown, and where it was logged.
            StackTraceElement[] to = new Throwable().getStackTrace();

            int i = trace.length - 1;
            int j = to.length -1;
            for(; i > -1 && j > -1; i--, j--, till--)
            {
                if (!trace[i].equals(to[j]))
                    break;                      
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < till; i++)
        {
            log(level, pad + "  at " + trace[i].toString());
        }

        if (till != trace.length)
            log(level, pad + "  at ...");

    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* warn -- log message if at WARN level or better                  */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log message if at WARN level or better.
     * 
     * @param msg output message
     */
    static public void warn (String msg)
    {
        log (WARN, msg) ;
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //* warn -- log exception if at WARN level or better                */
    //*******************************************************************/
    /**
     * Log exception if at WARN level or better.
     * 
     * @param e exception
     * @param detail DETAIL_LOW, DETAIL_MED, or DETAIL_FULL
     */
    static public void warn (Throwable e, int detail)
    {
        log (e, WARN, detail) ;
    }

    //*******************************************************************/
    //*                                                                 */
    //*         OBJECT METHODS                                          */
    //*                                                                 */
    //*******************************************************************/

    //*--private object methods-----------------------------------------*/

    //*--protected object methods---------------------------------------*/

    //*--package object methods-----------------------------------------*/

    //*--public object methods------------------------------------------*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by using

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger cat = LogManager.getLogger(Logger.class.getName())
```

instead of what is used in the question.